# Discord.py Sending a message to specific guilds using webhooks

Tags: python, discord.py

So my server decided to start this tourney and in order to communicate with every other server, we wanted to create a command where we could use a webhook they sent over and use that to convey information.
Example:

```
Server1Webhook = "webhook url"

Server2Webhook = "webhook url"

Server3Webhook = "webhook url"
```

Is there a way to loop through all of the webhooks until every server got the message?

So far my code:

```py
@commands.command()
async def eventsend(self, ctx, webhook, *, reason):
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    eventweb = discord.Embed(title = "Incoming  Announcment!", color = 0xfad934, description = reason)
    webhook = Webhook.from_url('url', adapter=AsyncWebhookAdapter(session)) #something here to cycle through url's
    await webhook.send(embed = eventweb ,username='Solamita')
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of all variables that are webhook urls and then you can iterate through them

```py
l = [Server1Webhook, Server2Webhook, Server3Webhook]

@commands.command()
async def eventsend(self, ctx, webhook, *, reason):
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    eventweb = discord.Embed(title = "Incoming  Announcment!", color = 0xfad934, description = reason)
    for i in l:
        webhook = Webhook.from_url(i, adapter=AsyncWebhookAdapter(session)) #something here to cycle through url's
        await webhook.send(embed = eventweb ,username='Solamita')
```

Comment: It's giving me 2 errors. It's either the argument reason or missing or webhook is missing.